# "I am almost finished" vs "I almost have finished"

Tags: adverbs, present-perfect, present-simple

help me please.

Are these sentences both correct?

- I have almost finished the book.
- I am almost finished the book.

What the difference?

Can I also say "I almost finish the book"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have almost finished the book** is correct.  It's the [present perfect](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html), which uses "have" + past participle, and can be used to indicate an uncompleted action.

**I am almost finished the book** is wrong.  The present perfect uses *to have*, not *to be*.  But you could say **"I am almost finished *with* the book."**  This is an example of a [participial adjective](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/participle-adjectives.html).

**I almost finish the book** is the present tense.  It doesn't really make sense in isolation, but you could use in a sentence like "Every time I start reading a book, I almost finish the book, and then I get distracted."

Comment: "I am almost finished the book" is a pretty common expression. Note that being "finished *with* the book" does not imply that you've read the whole thing, whereas "finished the book" means you have read the whole thing.

Comment: A big thank you to you for your answer. The correct version of the sentence **"I am almost finished with the book"** is the same as **"I have almost finished the book"**?

Comment: @nnnnnn - "I am almost finished the book" is pretty common in what dialect?  Not in any I'm familiar with.  Can you provide any examples of it in live usage?

Comment: @SergeyBolotaev - You're very welcome!  I would say that "I am almost finished with the book" is almost exactly the same as "I have almost finished the book".  In this context, either one sounds good and means the same thing.

Comment: Well it was easy to find [an example](http://www.goodreads.com/questions/499221-dear-juliet-i-am-almost-finished-the-3rd) with Google, but I made that comment because I have personally heard people say that, and I've said it myself. I'm a native English speaker from Australia, if it matters.

Comment: Let me say again, "finished with the book" and "finished the book" do *not* mean the same thing. The latter means that you've read the whole thing, but "finished with the book" means you are no longer using it, which *might* be because you read the whole thing, or it might be that you got bored with it and don't intend to finish reading it, or that you just needed to read certain chapters for research purposes, etc.

Comment: If you've heard and said it, OK, but ["I am almost finished the" is so rare that Google Ngrams doesn't show any findings of it](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=am+almost+finished+the%2Cam+almost+finished+with+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cam%20almost%20finished%20with%20the%3B%2Cc0), and I would suggest that the great majority of web results you'll find are examples of typos, non-native speakers, or just plain sloppy writing.

Comment: *"finished with the book" and "finished the book" do not mean the same thing* - Your very own examples show that they can mean exactly the same thing, and I would posit that 99% of the time they do, although I'll agree that "finished with" can mean "done with" and not necessarily "completed" - someone might say, "Are you finished with that shovel?" which of course doesn't mean that the person has consumed it.

Comment: When I said I'd *heard* people say "I am almost finished the book", I meant that literally: it's not something I've seen *written* much at all (though there are examples), but in informal spoken conversation I've heard people say it reasonably often - maybe it's a regional thing? Though I've said it aloud myself, if writing I would say "I have almost finished..."

Comment: What about "I almost have 300 movies on my hard-drive?" is it correct?